# How to search for a directory or file in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

It's easy enough to find files containing a given string using CTRL+SHIFT+F or right-click->Find in Folder, but is there a way to search for a string in the name of the file or directory itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can quick-find via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> on Windows. I would highly suggest also installing the **[AutoFileName](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoFileName)** package via PackageControl.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on OS X so if you are on Windows or linux your key combo might be different but I use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> which opens the show files overlay where I can type in any part of a file name in the current project.  The overlay lists all files and filters as I type.

I think this is the same as Goto anything <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> but I've always used <kbd>t</kbd>

http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#goto-anything